# Read exe file as binary file in C#

Tags: c#, exe, binaryfiles

I want to read an exe file in my C# code then decode as base64.

I am doing it like this

```
FileStream fr = new FileStream(@"c:\1.exe", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fr);
fr.Read(data, 0, count);
```

But the problem is that when I write this file the written file gets corrupted.
When analyzing in hex workshop code value 20 in hex is being replaced by 0.

Comment: Just noticing:  Why do you create a StreamReader and then never use it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A StreamReader should be used only with text files. With binary files you need to use directly a FileStream or:

```
byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\1.exe");
string base64Encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
// TODO: do something with the bas64 encoded string

buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Encoded);
File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\2.exe", buffer);
```

Comment: Truth be told, if you're going to read and/or write an EXE, it's almost always better to treat it as a bunch of bytes throughout.  Base64-encoding creates more problems than it solves -- the string becomes nearly opaque, and you have to do a bit of conversion and tricky bit-shifting in order to get at the data.

Comment: @cHao, totally agree with you. It's just that the OP's intent is unclear. He talked about Base64 string so I showed only an example.

Answer (score 3):

StreamReader official docs:

"Implements a TextReader that reads characters from a byte stream in a particular encoding."

It's for text, not binary files.  Try just Stream or BinaryReader..  (Why did you try a StreamReader?)